# Django, Serving combined static files behine nginx with apache proxies?

Tags: django, apache, proxy, nginx

I've been looking into combining static files and serving them as one file. But how would I go about doing this when my django stack is on a apache proxy with a nginx loadbalancer?

regards
Bjarni I.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into nginx's [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files) directive. Write a view in your Django code that will compress the files and put them onto your nginx server (or something else it can access, like an NFS share), and then have nginx `try_files` for the version it has first, before falling back to your Django file cruncher if the file doesn't exist yet (at which point nginx would serve it next time).

Answer (score 0):

You might try [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/). In your settings module, you define groups of static files (js, css), that compress will, well, compress into one file per group. There's then a couple of template tags that you use to include the compressed files in your templates.

For example

```
#settings.py
COMPRESS_CSS = {
    'main': {
        'source_filenames': ('css/960gs.css', 
                             'css/main.css',
                             ),
        'output_filename': 'css/main.min.r?.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        },
    },

    # other CSS groups goes here
}
```

Then, somewhere in your templates (most likely your base template), you use `{% compressed_css 'main' %}`.

You can define multiple groups if you have some css/js that you want to include in all pages, but some you only want to include in certain pages, or whatever you need. It's pretty flexible.

You can also easily turn compression off for easy debugging.

It also adds a unique version number to the resulting compressed file(s) to get around browser caching problem. This is the `r?` portion of `output_filename`.

Comment: Ok, but then i would have to mount a folder from the apache machine to the nginx machine?

Comment: not necessarily, but you'd have to share the files somehow. If you're using a build tool like Fabric, you could write a build script that called synccompress (to generate the minified files), then copied those files from one machine to another (perhaps using SCP).